# I dont know why 'database connected' not showing in terminal

Tags: node.js, mongodb

**code**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
const MongoClient=require('mongodb').MongoClient

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});
router.post('/submit',function(req,res){
  console.log(req.body)

  MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/',function(err,client){
    if(err)
    console.log('error')
    else
    console.log('database connected')
  
  })
```

**Terminal Result**

POST /submit 200 313.786 ms - 6
GET / 304 9.512 ms - -
GET /stylesheets/style.css 304 1.273 ms - -
[Object: null prototype] {
first_name: 'aaaa',
last_name: 'aaa',
email: 'aaa',
pw: 'aaa',
pw_confirm: 'aaa'
}
POST /submit 200 15.479 ms - 6

**Expected Result**

[Object: null prototype] {
first_name: 'aaaa',
last_name: 'aaa',
email: 'aaa',
pw: 'aaa',
pw_confirm: 'aaa'
}
POST /submit 200 15.479 ms - 6
database connected

Comment: Please provide the whole block of `router.post('/submit',function(req,res){`

Comment: Mongod is active? Try with mongosh can it connect or no.

Answer (score 0):

You're attempting to connect to MongoDB via  `MongoClient` but i see that you are missing the database name in your connection URL. also you should handle the connection and access the database within the connection callback. your code with above fixes applied should be something like :

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});

router.post('/submit', function(req, res) {
  console.log(req.body);

  MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/db_name_here', function(err, client) {
    if (err) {
      console.log('Database connection error :', err);
      res.status(500).send('Database connection Failed');
    } else {
      console.log('Database connected');

      // DB operations here

      
      client.close();

     
      res.status(200).send('DB connected successfully');
    }
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Hope that fixes your error

Comment: thaks. but still my terminal not showing database connected.

Comment: @MohammedShibili did you replaced `db_name_here` with the actual name of your MongoDB database. Also Make sure that your MongoDB server is running check the MongoDB  port if you are using different port you need to change it in the connection string